# Celery does not execute group of chunks parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have list of chunks, which are filenames

```
chunks_list = [["file_1", "file_2", "file_3"], ["file_4", "file_5", "file_6"], ...]
```

I have a task which processes this chunks:

```
@celery_app.task
def process_files_task(files: List[str]):
    for file in files:
        logger.info(file)
        # processing each file
```

I need to run chunks **parallel**, and `chunks_list` has 8 chunks. So celery worker concurrency is also 8.
I run my tasks like this:

```
chunks_group = process_files_task.chunks([(chunk,) for chunk in chunks_list], 8).group()
chunks_group.delay().get()
```

The problem is that all tasks executed by only one worker. That's what I see in my logs:

```
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] file_1
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] file_2
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] file_3
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] file_4
...
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong to make every free forker execute the task

Answer (score 0):

You can set `worker_prefetch_multiplier` to 1.

> How many messages to prefetch at a time multiplied by the number of concurrent processes. The default is 4 (four messages for each process). The default setting is usually a good choice, however – if you have very long running tasks waiting in the queue and you have to start the workers, note that the first worker to start will receive four times the number of messages initially. Thus the tasks may not be fairly distributed to the workers.

more details [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-prefetch-multiplier).

Comment: tried to add `worker_prefetch_multiplier=1`, did not change anything. I've noticed that calling task.chunks() creates a starmap, which is mentioned to be sequential in official documentation

Comment: not sure how you formatted your logs, can you add there the PID/TID (process id/thread id) - it will be easier to understand what's going on that way https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.log.html#celery.app.log.TaskFormatter

Answer (score 0):

Docs aren't that clear on whether chunks are supposed to execute in parallel or not but they do mention that chunks can be converted to groups (which should be parallel).

Example from the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chunks):

```
>>> group = add.chunks(zip(range(100), range(100)), 10).group()
```